# Reserved disk space

Tags: linux, android

Is it possible to know who is using the reserved disk space i.e which process is using it ? I am trying to understand which process are trying to eat up the reserved disk space.I am new to this area and have no clue.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "reserved" ?  Who reserved it, and how was it reserved?

Answer (score 1):

There is no single answer to the question.

With the df -h command, you can see the space occupied by the folders on the basis of GiB. You can run the du -ah command for each folder. This command gives you the file size in the directory you are in.

```
du -ah /home/user
```

For example, if you don't want to see the size of the .txt files in the file directory, then you need to add the --exclude parameter:

```
du -ah --exclude = "*. txt" /home/user
```

There are many parameters related to the du command, and you can learn the information you want with these parameters.

By typing **man du**, you can access the parameters list.

You can still monitor by installing easier tools. I can recommend you **NCurses**. Thanks to this program, you can list without the need for du parameters.

By monitoring your system with advanced monitoring tools such as Grafana, you can receive notifications with the triggers you create.

Comment: Nice answer.  Just a note to clarify the `df` command, that lists the space for all files on a particular mount point.  You do imply that in your description of the `du` command.

Comment: "**Ncdu** is a disk usage analyzer with an ncurses interface." ncurses is merely a standard library used for whole-window text graphics. `https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu`.